# Root S4 mini SGH-i257M

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

A year or so ago I was looking into rooting my S4 mini SGH-i257M. This is the Canadian version, Android 4.4.2 from Rogers. At the time there was no reliable method available, and no hope of there being one in the near future. I am wondering if anyone has found a reliable root procedure for this phone since then.

```
S4 mini SGH-i257M
Baseband version i257MVLUBNG2
Kernal Version 3.4.0-2254622
Build number KOT49H.i257MVLUBNG2
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, a simple reliable root procedure has been found for this phone. It is **CF-Auto-Root** by **Chainfire**. Here is a quote from Chainfire's initial post outlining the philosophy of this procedure ...

***CF-Auto-Root is the root for "rooting beginners" and those who want to keep as close to stock as possible. CF-Root is meant to be used in combination with stock Samsung firmwares, and be the quickest and easiest way for your first root. In essence, it does nothing but install and enable SuperSU on your system, so apps can gain root access.***

Here is the link to the actual procedure ...
http://androidmtk.com/root-samsung-galaxy-s4-mini-sgh-i257m

Here is a link to my post on xda with the details of my results ...
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64690687&postcount=1329

Note that the procedure is for Build number KOT49H.i257MVLUBNG**1** but i took a bit of a risk with my phone which has Build number KOT49H.i257MVLUBNG**2** and it works flawlessly.